# Use map data offline with osmdroid

Tags: osmdroid

My ultimate goal is to have map data (offline, because I will customize it myself) and display it in an app (Android). I could make osmdroid work to load maps online and I was trying to figure out how to download and display offline maps. I downloaded MOBAC (Mobile Atlas Creator) and export the data to SQLite format and when I had a look at it I realized that tiles are saved in image format (PNG).

What I would like to do is to import data to the phone to later use it in algorithms such as a search engine or a routing algorithm, so I need the "nodes" and "ways" (as I get them from the original OSM XML), import them to the phone and visualize it to later have this data available for the algorithms I want to develop. Basically, what MAPS.ME does. I think it wouldn't be difficult to convert the XML into the SQLite since a simple script could make it, but then, how can I generate the tiles from this custom SQLite database? Or, is there a way I can download the data in a more appropriate way to do what I'm planning to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering the tiles in an app from raw Openstreetmap data would be computation heavy and inefficient. I would suggest to use image tiles you exported for visual representation.

In addition to tiles you should export a data set you will need in the application for desired functionality. You will not need all data from Openstreetmap so you should identify what you need and build your custom export (there are tools and libraries for processing and filtering of Openstreetmap data. I have used [pyosmium](http://osmcode.org/pyosmium/) for some filtering and processing but there are others.) For example, you can build your custom database with POIs you want to search for.

Routing is another chapter. You can implement it yourself but it is a very complex task. There is [java library called Graphopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper) which can do the data extraction (from Openstreetmap) and offline routing for you. They have an online API too but it is possible to make it working completely offline (I did it for one application). Try to look at the source code because than you can see how complex topic routing is. Final note: data exported from Graphopper contains information about some POIs along routes. It may be possible to search for some things via its java API but I haven't investigated this yet.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't thought about combining both having a database with the tiles and another with the POI. In regards to routing, how difficult do you think it is? Wouldn't it be simply implementing an algorithm like A* ?

Comment: @kuonb I think the challenge would be construction of a scored graph from  openstreetmap data. It can be done for sure, but it would require deep knowledge of osm data structure (maily [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) that can affect routing). Scoring itself can be tricky. That's basically what the Graphopper library does. But if you are really into it I guess you can give it a try. I would consider it not economically feasible but it depends on your specific project and constraints.